# Banach algebra problem: $\left\|e^{ta}\right\|\leq Me^{-\omega t}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital algebra, and $a\in A$. Assume that $\sigma(a)\subset \{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}: Re\lambda < 0\}$.

Show there exists $M,\omega >0$ such that $$\left\|e^{ta}\right\|\leq Me^{-\omega t} $$
for all $t>0$.

Even if $\sigma(a)$ contains an eigenvalue $\lambda$ i find this difficult since then (for an eigenvector $x$) $$\left\|e^{ta(x)}\right\|= \left\|e^{t\lambda x}\right\|
=\left\|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^k (\lambda x)^k/k!\right\|... $$

But i cant seem to reduce this further to something of the above form, let alone if $\sigma(a)$ contains no eigenvalues. Is there some handy trick involved? The inequality does remind me of inequalities I have seen in theory for dynamical systems where $a$ is instead some functions $g$.

Any hints of suggestions?

Comment: There's no such thing as "eigenvalues" and "eigenvectors" in a general Banach algebra.

Comment: Ha, you are right. I assumed that $A=B(X)$ bounded operators on a banach space. That is not the case here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For a suitable contour $\Gamma$,
$$ e^{ta} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\Gamma e^{tz} (z - a)^{-1}\ dz$$

Comment: Hey, Im still little bit stuck. I thought in some crazy way we could apply the residue Theorem here, for $\Gamma$ a contour surrounding $\sigma(a)$, but I'm afraid that's not allowed. How do we estimate the norm of this integral? It should be $$ e^{ta} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\Gamma e^{tz} (ze - a)^{-1}\ dz$$ (reading chapter 10 from Rudin).

Comment: $(ze-a)^{-1}$ is a continuous function of $z$, and therefore uniformly bounded on a compact set.  And $|e^{tz}| = e^{t \text{Re}(z)}$.  So...

Comment: Can the contour $\Gamma$  be made now such that $Re z < 0$ for all $z\in \Gamma$ and still surround whole $\sigma(a)$ ? (contour may contain 0)  Ok thanks, then this norm is bounded by $1/(2\pi) \sup_{z\in \Gamma}\left\|(ze-\alpha)^{-1}\right\|\cdot e^{Re(z)}$

Comment: So $\sigma(a)\subseteq \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}| Re \lambda < 0\}$. What  if $\sigma(a)$ has 0 as limit point, then $\Gamma$ must contain $z$ with Re $z \geq 0$. Does it then still follow?

Comment: $\sigma(a)$ is compact, so it contains all its limit points.

Comment: I see, so then there exists $\omega < 0$ such that $Re(\lambda)<\omega$ for all $\lambda \in \sigma(a)$. OK thanks.